# Differentiate the Function: $y=\sqrt{1+2{e^{3x}}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=\sqrt{1+2{e^{3x}}}$

I am using this formula $(e^{f(x)})'=e^{f(x)}\cdot f'(x)$

The Chain Rule $\begin{align*}
f'(x) = g'(h(x)) h'(x).
\end{align*}$

and the product rule $k(x)=f(x)g(x)\ then\ k'(x)=f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$

$y=(1+2e^{3x})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Chain Rule

$\frac{1}{2}(1+2e^{3x})^{-\frac{1}{2}}(0+2(e^{3x}(3)))$

$\frac{(6e^{3x})}{2\sqrt{1+2e^{3x}}}$

According to the book, my answer is wrong. Where in my process, using these rules, am I going wrong?

Comment: I think this needs clarification.  Do you mean $e^{3x}$ inside your square root?  As it stands, I believe you have written $e^3$x which is very different.

Comment: Is it $e^{3x}$ or $e^3x$ ?

Comment: I just fixed the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake is in the first step when you apply the chain rule. The derivative of $(f(x))^{1/2}=\frac{1}{2}(f(x))^{-1/2}f'(x).$